# Notepad++ where is the download folder for the update EXE

Tags: notepad++

Say i install an older version of Notepad++ from the setup.exe. (Windows 10 version)
After installation, Notepad++ detects that it is an older version, and asks me if I want to update.
If i say yes, it will start downloading a newer setup.exe. This will happen in the background, but I'd like to keep the newer .exe for future use.

So where is it hidden or downloaded to ?

Answer (score 0):

Like most products, the file is downloaded to the user's temporary folder.

To find the folder, start a Command Prompt and run one of the following commands:

```
set temp
echo %temp%
```

The name of the file usually looks like `npp.#.#.#.Installer.exe`.

Comment: Could you find it on your machine? [Everything](www.voidtools.com) here found only one manually downloaded npp*exe - so it looks like the file gets deleted after installation.

Comment: The best way to get such a file is to stash it away while the installation is waiting for user action. For many products, afterward is too late.